Fabricjs Handling events when items positions are recalculated
i need to have two "buttons" on a canvas with a mousedown event for each button.


const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("myCanvas");
const hoverLabel = document.getElementById('hoverLabel');
const MAX_HIDDEN_LAYER_NODES = 16;

class Node {
  constructor(canvas,x, y, fill, label, boardHash, peripheralHash, instructionHash) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.fill = fill;
    this.label = label;
    this.boardHash = boardHash;
    this.peripheralHash = peripheralHash;
    this.instructionHash = instructionHash;
    this.circle = this.createCircle();
  }

  createCircle() {
    const circle = new fabric.Circle({
      left: this.x,
      top: this.y,
      radius: 20,
      fill: this.fill,
      stroke: "black",
      strokeWidth: 2,
      selectable: false,
      hoverCursor: "pointer",
    });

    // Add event listeners for hover
    circle.on("mouseover", (e) => {
      circle.set({ stroke: "red", strokeWidth: 4 });
      this.canvas.renderAll();
      Node.showHoverLabel(this.label, e.e.clientX, e.e.clientY);
    });

    circle.on("mouseout", () => {
      circle.set({ stroke: "black", strokeWidth: 2 });
      this.canvas.renderAll();
      Node.hideHoverLabel();
    });

    // Add event listener for click
    circle.on("mousedown", () => {
      Node.showModal(
        this.label,
        this.boardHash,
        this.peripheralHash,
        this.instructionHash
      );
    });

    return circle;
  }

  setPosition(left, top) {
    this.circle.set({ left: left, top: top });
    this.circle.setCoords(); // Update the coordinates for the circle
  }

  getLeft() {
    return this.circle.left;
  }

  getTop() {
    return this.circle.top;
  }

  getRadius() {
    return this.circle.radius;
  }

  addToCanvas(canvas) {
    canvas.add(this.circle);
  }
  static showHoverLabel(text, x, y) {
    const hoverLabel = document.getElementById("hoverLabel");
    hoverLabel.style.display = "block";
    hoverLabel.style.left = `${x + 20}px`;
    hoverLabel.style.top = `${y}px`;
    hoverLabel.textContent = text;
  }

  static hideHoverLabel() {
    const hoverLabel = document.getElementById("hoverLabel");
    hoverLabel.style.display = "none";
  }

  static showModal(label, boardHash, peripheralHash, instructionHash) {
    const modal = document.getElementById("nodeModal");
    const modalText = document.getElementById("modalText");
    modalText.textContent = `Label: ${label}\nBoard Hash: ${boardHash}\nPeripheral Hash: ${peripheralHash}\nInstruction Hash: ${instructionHash}`;
    modal.style.display = "block";

    const span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    span.onclick = function () {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    };

    window.onclick = function (event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    };
  }
}


class Network {
  constructor(canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.inputs = [];
    this.layers = [];
    this.labels = [];
    this.outputs = [];
  }

  getVerticalCenter(numElements, elementIndex) {
    const totalHeight = numElements * 40 + (numElements - 1) * 30;
    return (this.canvas.getHeight() - totalHeight) / 2 + elementIndex * 70;
  }

  updateVerticalPositions() {
    let yOffset = 0;

    this.inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
      const y = this.getVerticalCenter(this.inputs.length, index);
      input.setPosition(input.getLeft(), y);
      yOffset = y + 70;
    });

    this.layers.forEach((layer, layerIndex) => {
      yOffset = 0;
      layer.forEach((neuron, index) => {
        const y = this.getVerticalCenter(layer.length, index);
        neuron.setPosition(neuron.getLeft(), y + yOffset);
      });

      // Update the position of the buttons
      const yTop = this.getVerticalCenter(layer.length + 2, 0);
      const layerLeft = layer[0].getLeft(); // Adjust as necessary

      layer.addButton.set({ left: layerLeft, top: yTop });
      layer.removeButton.set({ left: layerLeft + 30, top: yTop });

      // // Remove old event handlers before reassigning
      // layer.addButton.off("mousedown");
      // layer.removeButton.off("mousedown");

      // // Assign new event handlers with updated layerIndex
      // layer.addButton.on("mousedown", () => this.addNodeToLayer(layerIndex));
      // layer.removeButton.on("mousedown", () =>
      //   this.removeNodeFromLayer(layerIndex)
      // );

      yOffset += layer.length * 70 + 30;
    });

    yOffset = 0;
    this.outputs.forEach((output, index) => {
      const y =
        this.getVerticalCenter(this.outputs.length, Math.floor(index)) +
        yOffset;
      this.labels[index].setPosition(this.labels[index].getLeft(), y);
      output.setPosition(output.getLeft(), y);
    });

    this.canvas.renderAll();
  }

  updateHorizontalPositions() {
    const canvasWidth = this.canvas.getWidth();
    const minX = 70;
    const maxX = canvasWidth - 170;
    const totalLayers = this.layers.length + 1;

    const layerWidth = (maxX - minX) / totalLayers;

    this.layers.forEach((layer, index) => {
      const layerLeft = minX + (index + 0.5) * layerWidth;

      layer.forEach((neuron) => {
        neuron.setPosition(50 + layerLeft, neuron.getTop());
      });

      // Update the position of the buttons
      if (layer.length > 0) {
        layer.addButton.set({ left: layerLeft + 50 });
        layer.removeButton.set({ left: layerLeft + 30 + 50 });

        // // Remove old event handlers before reassigning
        // layer.addButton.off("mousedown");
        // layer.removeButton.off("mousedown");

        // // Log current button positions and index
        // console.log("Layer index:", index);
        // console.log(
        //   "Add button position:",
        //   layer.addButton.left,
        //   layer.addButton.top
        // );
        // console.log(
        //   "Remove button position:",
        //   layer.removeButton.left,
        //   layer.removeButton.top
        // );

        // // Assign new event handlers with updated index
        // layer.addButton.on("mousedown", () => {
        //   console.log("Add button clicked for layer index:", index);
        //   this.addNodeToLayer(index);
        // });

        // layer.removeButton.on("mousedown", () => {
        //   console.log("Remove button clicked for layer index:", index);
        //   this.removeNodeFromLayer(index);
        // });
      }
    });

    this.canvas.renderAll();
  }
  addInput() {
    const x = 50; // Initial x, will be updated in updateNeuronPositions
    const y = 50; // Initial y, will be updated in updateNeuronPositions
    const boardHash = "boardHash";
    const peripheralHash = "peripheralHash";
    const instructionHash = "instructionHash";
    const input = new Node(
      this.canvas,
      x,
      y,
      "blue",
      `Input ${this.inputs.length + 1}`,
      boardHash,
      peripheralHash,
      instructionHash
    );

  

    this.inputs.push(input);
    input.addToCanvas(this.canvas);
    this.updateVerticalPositions();
  }

  addHiddenLayer() {
    const numNeurons = parseInt(
      prompt("Enter number of neurons in the hidden layer:", 4)
    );
    const layerIndex = this.layers.length;
    const canvasWidth = this.canvas.getWidth();
    const totalLayers = this.layers.length + 1;

    const minX = 100;
    const maxX = canvasWidth - 100;
    const layerWidth = (maxX - minX) / totalLayers;
    const layerLeft = minX + (layerIndex + 0.5) * layerWidth;

    const layer = [];
    const x = 50; // Initial x, will be updated in updateNeuronPositions
    const y = 50; // Initial y, will be updated in updateNeuronPositions
    const boardHash = "boardHash";
    const peripheralHash = "peripheralHash";
    const instructionHash = "instructionHash";
    for (let i = 0; i < numNeurons; i++) {
      const neuron = new Node(
        this.canvas,
        x + layerLeft,
        y,
        "blue",
        `Layer ${layerIndex + 1} Neuron ${i + 1}`,
        boardHash,
        peripheralHash,
        instructionHash
      );
      layer.push(neuron);
      neuron.addToCanvas(this.canvas);
    }

    // Add buttons for adding/removing neurons
    const addButton = new fabric.Circle({
      left: layerLeft - 40,
      top: y,
      fill: "green",
      selectable: false,
      hoverCursor: "pointer",
      radius: 5,
      stroke: "black",
      strokeWidth: 2,
    });

    const removeButton = new fabric.Circle({
      left: layerLeft - 60,
      top: y + 40,
      fill: "red",
      selectable: false,
      hoverCursor: "pointer",
      radius: 5,
      stroke: "black",
      strokeWidth: 2,
    });

    addButton.on("mousedown", () => {
      this.addNodeToLayer(layerIndex);
    });
    removeButton.on("mousedown", () => {
      this.removeNodeFromLayer(layerIndex);
    });

    this.canvas.add(addButton);
    this.canvas.add(removeButton);

    // Save buttons to the layer for future positioning
    layer.addButton = addButton;
    layer.removeButton = removeButton;

    this.layers.push(layer);
    this.updateVerticalPositions();
    this.updateHorizontalPositions();
  }

  addOutput() {
    const boardHash = "boardHash";
    const peripheralHash = "peripheralHash";
    const instructionHash = "instructionHash";
    const numOutputs = this.outputs.length / 2;
    const y = this.getVerticalCenter(numOutputs + 1, numOutputs);

    const label = new Node(
      this.canvas,
      950,
      350,
      "red",
      `Label ${this.outputs.length + 1}`,
      boardHash,
      peripheralHash,
      instructionHash
    );
    const output = new Node(
      this.canvas,
      1050,
      350,
      "red",
      `Output ${this.outputs.length + 1}`,
      boardHash,
      peripheralHash,
      instructionHash
    );

 

    this.labels.push(label);
    this.outputs.push(output);
    label.addToCanvas(this.canvas);
    output.addToCanvas(this.canvas);

  }

  addNodeToLayer(layerIndex) {
    const layer = this.layers[layerIndex];
    if (layer.length < MAX_HIDDEN_LAYER_NODES) {
      const newNode = new Node(
        this.canvas,
        layer[0].getLeft(),
        layer[layer.length - 1].getTop() + 70,
        "blue",
        `Layer ${layerIndex + 1} Neuron ${layer.length + 1}`,
        "boardHash",
        "peripheralHash",
        "instructionHash"
      );
      layer.push(newNode);
      newNode.addToCanvas(this.canvas);

      this.updateVerticalPositions();
      this.updateHorizontalPositions();
    }
  }

  removeNodeFromLayer(layerIndex) {
    const layer = this.layers[layerIndex];
    if (layer.length > 1) {
      const nodeToRemove = layer.pop();
      this.canvas.remove(nodeToRemove.circle);

      this.updateVerticalPositions();
      this.updateHorizontalPositions();
    } else {
      alert("Cannot remove the last node in the layer");
    }
  }

}

const network = new Network(canvas);
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
#controls {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
button {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
#myCanvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#hoverLabel {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}

 /* Add some basic styling for the modal */
 .modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<div id="controls">
    <button onclick="network.addInput()">Add Input</button>
    <button onclick="network.addHiddenLayer()">Add Hidden Layer</button>
    <button onclick="network.addOutput()">Add Output</button>
  </div>
  <div id="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1200" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>

  <div id="nodeModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <p id="modalText">Some text in the Modal..</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="hoverLabel"></div>



and after adding them to the canvas, it will work.
But then i have two functions to move the top and left coordinates of those buttons according to other items i have.
The position of the items will move correctly, but the mousedown event will not, it stays at the initial coordinates (at the yellow marks).
enter image description here
I tried to remove and reassing the event but nothing.
Have you got any ideas how to resolve the problem?

Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

there you have it :D
